# calculating duration of 1 cycle

Tags: javascript, math

I'm working on RGBGenerator, I want to calculate how many seconds it needs to do 1 cycle;
Forumla:

```
ticks it needs for 1 cycle * speed / 1000 = seconds
ticks it needs for 1 cycle * speed / 1000 / 60 = minutes
```

But it calculates it wrong; example:
If it needs 1791 ticks and the speed is 10ms/tick it needs 17.9 seconds (18 seconds). When I start a countdown it takes longer then 18seconds to do one cycle.

Calculate how many ticks it needs:

```
var r = settings.startR, g = settings.startG, b = settings.startB, range = settings.range, states = [], tick = 0;
states.push(Math.max(Math.abs((r - range)), Math.abs((g - range)), Math.abs((b- range))));
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    states.push((states[i]+1) + range);
}
```

Calculating seconds/minutes:

```
$( "#cycleSeconds" ).html("1 cycle = " + ((states[6]*speed/1000) >= 60 ? Math.round((states[6]*speed/1000/60)) + " minutes" : Math.round((states[6]*speed/1000)) + " seconds"));
```

[Live demo](http://rgbgenerator.com/dev/) (you need to set the speed input to the left and press start)

Does somebody know why it calculates it wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: try parseFloat before assigning any variable to var like            var r = parseFloat(settings.startR)

Comment: I did parseInt, no numbers in this case are floating, but it not fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For more accurate drawing use [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) instead of setTimeout.

You actually do something like this:

1. paint
2. wait for some time
3. goto 2

You probably didn't count the time which is spent to paint & other calculations. That is why the duration is more than `tick * count`.

Just in case: [Performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now%28%29) will help you to measure execution time quite accurately.

Comment: Hmm, but how to control the speed?

Comment: window.requestAnimationFrame allows you to use 60fps rate, which should becomes the starting point of your speed calculations.

Comment: Do you have a example for speedcontroling? I don`t understand it. I thinks tick it needs / 60 = seconds or something?